# How to refactor this React.js code without breaking the Rule Of Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my React application, I have a function that `myFunc2()` that calls `React.useContext()`.

Inside my function component (named `myFunc1()`), I do the following:

```
const runMyFunc2 = myFunc2()
runMyFunc2(args1)
runMyFunc2(args2)
```

Now I want to implement debouncing of these two consecutive calls to `runMyFunc2()`.
So I create a new function `myFunc3()`, outside of `myFunc1()` that looks like this:

```
const runMyFunc2 = myFunc2()

function myFunc3(): void {
  console.log('inside myFunc3!')
  runMyFunc2(args1)
  runMyFunc2(args2)
}
```

And I replace the three lines shown above from `myFunc1()` with a single call to `myFunc3()`, so that I can wrap them in [this call](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) to `debounce()`.

However just doing the above refactor -- without even calling `debounce()` -- produces this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

How can I refactor these two calls to `runMyFunc2()` so that I can debounce them without breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)?

Comment: Please show some actual code with components instead of anonymized `myFunc1`, `myFunc2`, `myFunc3`...

Comment: Either way, `const runMyFunc2 = myFunc2()` in global scope would attempt to use the `useContext` hook outside of component context, which is plain wrong.